# JS Regex Add Spaces to string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a two-part string and parts always delimited by space and |. Like this:

```
teststring | secondstring
```

It's possible to add predefined count of space between parts using ONLY Javascript `regex.replace()`?

I tried something like this:

```
([^\|]+)(\s){0,17}(?(R2)\s|\s)([\|a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

And Substitution:

```
$1$2$3
```

It's possible to repeat capture group in substitution e.g. `$2{17}` or match same space multiple times?

EDIT:
I have function

```
function InvokeRegexp(originalString, pattern, replaceExpr)
{
    return originalString.replace(pattern, replaceExpr);
}
```

and i want to pass two-part text, pattern containing number of spaces or replaceExpr containin number of spaces and get result: firstpart  | secondpart

Comment: *ONLY Javascript regex.replace()?* why? Split is probably more elegant here...

Comment: Could you tell what is the expected output also?

Comment: Expected output: teststring <count space what passed to regex>| secondstring

Comment: regex doesn't count, although it can match a specific (or range) of tokens with quantifiers...

Comment: i have only function what can't be changed and take a string, regex pattern, replace subtitution and random number of spaces

Comment: I think you need to more clearly lay out what your actual situation is, along with current input/output and expected input/output.

Comment: Are the spaces around the pipe in input alway the same? Or do you want to kind of sanitize your input

Comment: @lumio spaces around the pipe optional, for input i construct string from two parts, that must be delimited by |. First part have length <50, but as a result it must be 50 chars. I decide to pad it with spaces, but have only RegEx for it :)

Comment: Ok, so you want [String.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [String.padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) and use it on the strings before you concat them

Answer (score 0):

A non regex answer:

```
 str.split("|").join(
  " ".repeat(9 /*whitespaces*/) + "|"
 )
```

Or with regex its probably:

```
str.replace(/\|/," ".repeat(9)+"|")
```

Comment: Never seen `.repeat()` before. That's awesome :)

Comment: Where does it say 9 spaces?

Comment: "...to add predefined count of spaces between parts"

Comment: Right. My bad :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP already knows how to create a string with a given number of spaces in it - the question really makes no sense as currently stated, though.

Comment: @sweaver2112 *It's possible to add predefined count of space between parts?* ... :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd). Because you said you want them to have a certain length.

```js
const input = 'teststring  |    secondstring';

// Split the input variable and select spaces as well.
// 1. Select multiple spaces: \s+
// 2. Select pipe: \|
// 3. Select all following spaces: \s+
const parts = input.split( /\s+\|\s+/ );

// So every part should be at least 20 chars in this example.
const len = 20;
const output = `${ parts[ 0 ].padEnd( len ) }|${ parts[ 1 ].padStart( len )}`;

console.log( output );
```